# Insert text into a <textarea> when a button is clicked, where the cursor was positioned

Tags: javascript, cursor, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` with several buttons underneath it, and the purpose of these buttons is to insert certain text in to the `<textarea>`.

The below code will always insert the desired text at the beginning of the `<textarea>`, which is fine if it didn't have focus when the button was clicked. However, if the `<textarea>` did have focus, I'd like to insert the text where the cursor was when a button is clicked.

Here is my code so far. If anyone can suggest how I would need to do this, I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var button_text = {} // The text to insert for each button click

    button_text['insert_event_name']        = 'event_name';
    button_text['insert_event_date']        = 'event_date';
    button_text['insert_event_start_time']  = 'event_start';
    button_text['insert_event_finish_time'] = 'event_finish';
    button_text['insert_event_location']    = 'event_location';
    button_text['insert_event_address']     = 'event_address';

    jQuery('.inserter', '#event-desc-container').on('click', function(){

        var button = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        var text = '['+button_text[button]+']';

        textarea = jQuery('textarea#event_desc', '#event-desc-container');
        desc = textarea.val()

        textarea.val(text+desc);

    });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308292/inserting-text-at-cursor-in-a-textarea-with-javascript/3308539#3308539

Comment: Doesn't work, because as soon as I press a button, the textarea loses focus, and therefore `selectionStart`, `selectionEnd`, etc. are all `undefinded`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, so you need to work out how to prevent that. Calling `focus()` on the textarea and calling `preventDefault()` on the `click` event will work in most browsers. Adding `unselectable="on"` will make it work in IE. Alternatively, use the `mousedown` event instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469420/how-to-append-text-in-textarea-at-cursor-location-using-javascript

Comment: Tim, that's that basis of this question - I don't know how to prevent that! Any way, it's resolved now. Thanks.

Comment: It's a simple fix that I would think is better to try to understand than to throw jQuery plug-ins at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be easily done with this jQuery plugin:
http://dwieeb.github.io/jquery-textrange/

Comment: Doesn't work. No matter how you use it you get the error `invalid 'in' operand` on line 190 (Firefox 22.0). Thanks.

Comment: Strange. Have you tried the demo.html. If I understood correctly that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I take my comment back, it was my coding error. Got it working fine now, and it does just what I'm after (with two lines of code!). Thanks for the tip.