# Insert into form curly brackets alias with Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I am not even sure if this is even possible or how easy it is, but what I am trying to work out is how to, if it is possible, to use jquery or javascript to insert an alias for a form field / curly brackets where the cursor currently is selected on the page.

Let me try and explain it a bit better.......

So I go to the email template form, on the right of the form I have 3 buttons,

```
NAME , REP , DATE
Name = {leadname}
Business Name = {businessname}
Date = {datesent}
```

These are all form fields being posted into the $form->data array when it loads.

I start writing out my template so.......Dear {leadname} etc etc
when the template is sent, it loads the clients name etc into the curly brackets and sends it in an email.

What I am trying to do is make this so that someone doesnt write leadname for the persons name but presses the button to the right of the form marked 'Name' , this then inserts [Name] or maybe Name in bold into the form, but this is actually an alias of {leadname} , so im not sure if I have to change my language file too to get this to work ?, im also not sure how to actually insert these fields into my template form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this kind of what you're talking about doing?
http://alexking.org/projects/js-quicktags/demo/index.html

If so, I think this guys implementation of JavaScript quick tags will get you going:
http://alexking.org/blog/2004/06/03/js-quicktags-under-lgpl/

Otherwise, this post may help you out: [Inserting a text where cursor is using Javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery)

-

### Edit

Here's the code you need, using Alex King's plugin to create a button that doesn't get closed:

```
edButtons.push(
    new edButton(
        'leader_name'
        ,'LEADER'
        ,'{leadname}'
        ,-1
        ,-1
    )
);
```

Comment: Cool, I like the look of that, I will have a look and see if I can get it working, thanks :-)

Comment: It seems to work pretty well, one thing im not sure of though it says :

Comment: var edButtons = new Array();
var edLinks = new Array();
var edOpenTags = new Array();

function edButton(id, display, tagStart, tagEnd, access, open) {
 this.id = id;    // used to name the toolbar button
 this.display = display;  // label on button
 this.tagStart = tagStart;  // open tag
 this.tagEnd = tagEnd;  // close tag
 this.access = access;   // set to -1 if tag does not need to be closed
 this.open = open;   // set to -1 if tag does not need to be closed
}

edButtons.push(
 new edButton(
  'ed_bold'
  ,'Name'
  ,'{leadname}'
  ,'{leadname}'
 )
);

Comment: but I am not sure where to add ------    this.open = open;   // set to -1 if tag does not need to be closed

Comment: }

edButtons.push(
 new edButton (
 'access'='-1'
 ,'open'='-1'
  ,'ed_bold'
  ,'Name'
  ,'{leadname}'
  ,'{leadname}'
 )