# Stop caret jumping to bottom of textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea with a lot of text in it, and I have code so that when you press Shift+Enter, it will insert a piece of text. However, at the moment, as soon as that happens, the text scrolls so that the carets at the bottom of the screen.

My insert code:

```
$("#body textarea").bind('keydown', function(event) {
    var caret = $("#body textarea").caret();
    if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey)
    {
        var text = "[br]"
        insertText("#body textarea", caret.start, caret.end, text, "");
        $("#body textarea").caret(caret.start+(text.length), caret.start+(text.length));
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what I can do to stop it forcing the caret to the bottom?

Cheers
BlackWraith

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Sorry about the delay, it didn't want to play nicely, but heres the example. Note, it only jumps to the bottom if you scroll down a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery) same trouble and make sample for you
http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/WAZBQ/

Comment: However, just as a note, I was hoping for a jquery answer, this is more javascript than jquery... just sayin. Thanks though, it'll still do what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Caret Position manually after inserting your text:

See http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/:

```
function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;   // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
    ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();
        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    return (CaretPos);
}

function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos){
    if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

ctrl is your textarea-element.

```
setCaretPosition(document.getElementById("textarea", 0);
```