# How can I implement autocompletion in a multiline <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, textarea

Basically the functionality that I'm trying to replicate is the @reply system as it works here on StackOverflow. I have a list of comments, and I want the user to be able to type @ and see suggestions of usernames from all previous comments.

I only found solutions that work on simple `<input type="text">`, but not on a multiline `<textarea>`.

I don't really care about compatibility with IE or legacy browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is attach a keyup event handler to the textarea and in that handler you need to catch when the ctrl + 2 key combination is pressed.  When you catch this, you need to show a popup containing your list of comments.  When a comment is selected (clicked), insert the selected comment at the cursor position of the textarea.  Here is a good example of how to do the last part - http://alexking.org/blog/2003/06/02/inserting-at-the-cursor-using-javascript.  Everything before is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Here is an example that is a bit more recent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery.