# change tab key behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a text editor inside a contenteditable div.

I need to change the [TAB] behavior to insert spaces or a \t instead of focusing on next element which is the default browser behavior.

I have an event handler like so:

```
function keyDown(e) {
    // press tab.
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}
```

which results in not losing focus on the div, all i need now is to insert a [TAB] or spaces at the cursor position.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/eFLGZ/

```
$('textarea').keydown(keyDown);

function keyDown(e) {

    // press tab.
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Insert a space.
        var txt = $('textarea').val();
        $('textarea').val(txt + ' ');

        return;
    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery) for how to enter the text where the cursor is currently placed.

Comment: this will add the space at the end of the text, but what if im editing in the middle of the textarea?

Comment: I guess we'll never know