# jQuery: modifying input value on keypress

Tags: jquery, replace, keypress

Whenever a dot '.' is typed in my input (type=number) field, I want it replaced by a comma ','.

```
$(box).find('input[type=number]').keypress(function(evt){
        if(evt.which==46){
            $(this).val($(this).val()+',');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

The event is well fired, but instead, the field gets totally empty. What's wrong?

**EDIT**

The reason why I'm doing this is that Chrome (latest version), contrary to the HTML5 recommandation, use comma and discard dot in input type=number. I'm currently only developing for Chrome cause I can't test my app somewhere else for the moment. Any comment on this (abnormal ?) situation would be appreciated.

Comment: It is recommended to use `keyup` event instead.

Comment: does a `alert($(this).val())` display anything

Comment: input `type="number"` will not accept comma `,`. You may have to change input `type=text`

Comment: @MuthuKumaran : actually that's what W3C says about type=number, but  Chrome on the contrary only accepts commas, and delete dots and anything coming afterwards. That's why I wanted to do this in the first place.

Comment: @VisioN : keyup does not even fire the event.

Comment: @Naryl : Yes, the previous value is well captured

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
```

This might work if you are typing and always want to put the ',' sign at the end of the text. But what if you put the cursor in the middle of the text and then press a '.' sign?

Comment: Found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your document isn't already ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: the OP specifically states "***The event is well fired, but..***"

Answer (score 0):

here we are my friend, don't know why, it seems the useful keycode is 190 instead of 110.

try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).find('input[type=number]').live('keydown',function(evt){
            if(evt.which == 190){
                $(this).val($(this).val()+",");
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
        });

});
```

and this for a live preview
http://jsfiddle.net/RTEcJ/8/

take a look at keycodes and you can try in the input to check which is the keycode you need:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.6, `on()` won't work. More importantly, with `keyup`, `evt.which` matches the keycode and not the charcode. Instead of 46, it will be 110 for numpad dot, and others for other ways to do it (depending on keyboard mapping).

Comment: try now please, then i really suggest you to update you jQuery vers.

Comment: @pHCito fixed now sorry for delay ;)

Comment: No matter if using .keypress, .keyup, .keydown, .bind(press/up/down), .live(press/up/down). Same behaviour.

Comment: @pHCito can you tell me the jquery version you are using? did you checked the jsfiddle? if you want to replace points with commas when writing down in the text input, it works greatly!!

Comment: Frankly, I don't know what to say. Your jsFiddle doesn't work on my side. It gets blank when pressing dot, I assure you. (I'm using 1.6.4 as you set the fiddle)

Comment: @pHCito so strange i think you have problems on your side, browser or somenthing else, for me it works perfectly, me i'm on mac + FF, don't know about you

Comment: I am a bit late, sorry. But it is the keycode for NumPad "."

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a substring like so:

```
str.substring(0,str.length - 1) + ','
```

However this is probably not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work while running it on jsfiddle:

```
$(document).find('input').keypress(function(evt){ 
        if(evt.which==46){
            $(this).val($(this).val()+',');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cornel_gav/cDE3L/

Comment: It will work for input `type=text` but OP is using input `type=number`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the char replacement work at any cursor position, you could bind to the keyup event and replace the already inserted Character in this.val().

```
$(document).on('keyup','.myField"]', function(e,i){
    if(e.keyCode==107)
    {
        var start = this.selectionStart,
            end = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\+/,'|'));
        this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work as val() doesn't return anything in a number of browsers if the input is invalid...