# How to add text to textarea when user clicks a button

Tags: html, onclick, textarea

I want to add text to textarea when user clicks a button.I know how to concate string and add it to textarea but what i want is to add text to the place/position inside textarea where users clicks and then add text in that position on clicking button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as mentioned above i did concating string on button click with already existing text inside textarea.

Comment: i need to add text to the user clicked position inside textarea

Comment: Where's you code buddy?

Comment: I think this is what you're trying to get at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 4):

Here's a reference from me:

```
<script>
function input(){
    var text = "here the text that you want to input.";
    document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
}    
</script>
<form name='form1'>
    Click<input onclick='input()' type='button' value='BUTTON' id='button'><br>
    <textarea name='area'></textarea>

</form>
```

that an example that showing when a button clicked, a row of text added to textarea.
why do i added javascript in it? because html attributes only is not enough to make it.
may it help :D

Comment: If you want to append the new text, just put the current text at the textarea into a variable and then mix it with your new text

Answer (score 4):

You need to add text at specific position (at caret position) into the text area when you click on a button. Try the following:

```js
var position;
 
    function getCaretPosition() {
        var ctlTextArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
        position = ctlTextArea.selectionStart;
        return position;
    }
 
 /* Needs JQuery */
    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.fn.extend({
            insertAtCaret: function (myValue) {
                return this.each(function (i) {
                    if (document.selection) {
                        //For browsers like Internet Explorer
                        this.focus();
                        sel = document.selection.createRange();
                        sel.text = myValue;
                        this.focus();
                    }
                    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
                        //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
                        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
                        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
                        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                        this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
                        this.focus();
                        this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
                        this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
                        this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                    } else {
                        this.value += myValue;
                        this.focus();
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        $('#btnTest').click(function () {
            $("#textArea").insertAtCaret(' << inserted text! >> ');
        });

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>How to add text to textarea when user clicks a button</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
// The javascript code goes here...
</script>

<body>
  
<h1>How to add text to textarea when user clicks a button</h1>
<div id="divDroppedFields">
    <textarea id="textArea" name="txtMessageFields" class="required" cols="80" rows="10" onclick="getCaretPosition()" onkeyup="getCaretPosition()">
 In the meantime the cat slowly recovered. The socket of the lost eye presented, it is true, a frightful appearance, but he no longer appeared to suffer any pain.
 </textarea>
</div>
<button id="btnTest">CLICK ME</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a simple way using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

your html

```
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="add text" id="add" />
```

Your Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('test');
  });
});
```

you can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/V2xBW/)

Comment: What if you want to add 2 paragraphs? how would you pass HTML into it?

Comment: @YacoZaragoza try `$('#txtarea, #txtarea2').html('test');`

Comment: This does not add text instead it replaces the existing text with the new text.