# How to change only one line in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea and every time the user enters "enter", I would like to populate the current line with a value.

I want to nudge the user to start each line with a certain phrase, such as "I am".

HTML:

```
  <textarea class="texty"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.texty {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".texty").bind("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            // User entered a newline.
            // Start the line with the phrase "I am"
            console.log("enterrrrr");
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FvePz/)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you want it to insert text at cursor position there are a lot of other solutions - just search Google. Check e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1064089/2028935

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/): Event fired when a key is released on the keyboard.
[`.keydown()`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/): Event fired when a key is pressed on the keyboard.

As you are trying to start new line with "I am" you should use `.keyup()` which will fire when a key is released.

If you want to add text `I am` at the end of the textarea value.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".texty").bind("keyup", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(this).val($(this).val()+"I am ");
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/FvePz/1/)**

If you would like to add `I am at any place when user press enter. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".texty").bind("keyup", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var caretPos = $('.texty')[0].selectionStart;
            var textAreaTxt = $(this).val();
            var txtToAdd = "I am ";
            $(this).val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/FvePz/5/)**

Comment: If I press some times `enter` and then return some lines back and press `enter` again, your code doesn't work properly.

Comment: @user3132718: Check fiddle its workfing fine. Can you explain in which case its not working?

Comment: press 3 times `enter`. Then go on line 2 and press enter again.

Comment: @user3132718 - the requester did not specify if this is a valid option  or not (to append text to the textarea) so until then this is a good/simple solution

Comment: @user3132718: Updated answer with both cases. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. You just needed to append the text to the element.

You can do this with `.val()`:

```
$('.texty').val($('.texty').val() + '\nI am');
e.preventDefault(); // We already appended a new line before "I am", so prevent default enter action
```

[See your updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvePz/3/)

Answer (score -1):

use keypress event instead of keydown

```
$('.texty').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) {
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/7ZP4Y/1/)

Comment: This is not the answer to the question - at best it is an improvement of his existing code