# append an image tag inside content editable div at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `contentEditable` div and a list of `emojies` images. What I am trying to do is that when a user click on an image, the image tag should be inserted at the cursor position.

I tired to do this but this code only insert the image at the end of the div which is not the case for me

```
$("#editable").append($(this).id); // $(this) is the image tag
```

How can I fix my problem?
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7VNTn/

Comment: can u produce a fiddle..

Comment: Can you provide the needed code to reproduce the issue? also `$(this).id` is wrong, should be `$(this).attr('id')`, `$(this).prop('id')`, `this.id` or at least `$(this)[0].id`

Comment: This may be your answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1064139/2394259

Comment: i'll add my fiddle in few sec

Comment: please check my updates

Answer (score 8):

try this code , change "IMAGE URL" with any image url

```
var image = '<p><img src="IMAGE URL" ></p>';

var sel, range, node;
if (window.getSelection) {
sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
node = range.createContextualFragment(image);
            range.insertNode(node);
          }
   } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
               document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(image);
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use following code.

```
        $("#editable").html($(this).id);
```

append method adds the element after your editable tag.So html method will put image inside youe row.try this

Comment: This will change the entire div content. OP wants to add the image at the cursor position

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#image1").click(function(){
    $("#editable").prepend($(this));
    });


});
```

I used prepend instead of append since you want the image to appear before the text.