# jQuery - Position cursor AFTER inserting text in textarea

Tags: jquery, position, cursor, textarea

My question is simple, but I can't figured it out.

I'm inserting text in the textarea, using a method that I found around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery). That method, insert the text in the actual cursor position, that's fine.

But I want to position the cursor between the inserted text.
The text I'll be inserting is:`****`, `__`, `~~~~` and `[](http://)`
I know, it's just some random symbols. But it is for a eregi.
I want to position the cursor between the chracters inserted, on `**here**`, `_here_` and `~~HERE~~`, the last one I need to position between the first [], it is `[HERE](http://)`.

It shouldn't be that hard, but I just don't know how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following functions:

Working Example [Caret Test](http://alanamel.org/caret.php)

```
function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  } else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos(input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}

$("#addStarsCode").click(function() {
  var my_i_val = $("#my_textarea").val();

  $("#my_textarea").val(my_i_val + '****');
  setCaretToPos($("#my_textarea")[0], $("#my_textarea").val().length-2);
});
<textarea id=my_textarea name=my_textarea> I Am A Default Text</textarea><br>
<button id=addStarsCode>Add ****</button>
```