# Adding text on button click to simple form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm starting out with jQuery, and I'm trying to add bootstrap buttons that add Spanish-accent vowels to the simple_form text field on click. I'm modeled the code after an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery) question, but nothing is currently happening upon clicking the button--am I doing something wrong?

In the view, I'm using simple form and adding a wrapper id to the text field:

```
<%= simple_form_for @word, url: lesson_image_spelling_path(current_lesson, @word.word), method: :patch do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :spelling_attempt, wrapper_html: { id: 'txt' }, label: "Spell the word:" %>

    <br>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="a-accent">á</button>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

In application.js I have:

```
jQuery("#a-accent").on('click', function() {
  var $txt = jQuery("#txt");
  var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
  var txtToAdd = "test";
  $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
});
```

Comment: Wrap your jquery in a `document.ready(function(){...})` or or make the click event handler attached global `$(document).on('click','#a-accent', function(){..})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use input_html instead of wrapper_html. 
Put console.log('btn clicked') into your click event and look in browser console if this event work.

Comment: A combination of input_html plus the document.ready(function) suggested by Rik did the trick :)