# Get click character position inside an input (not coordinate)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the character position of a click inside an input. Meaning that if my input has the text `abcdef` and I click between the `b` and the `c` my click listener (inside my input element) would return `2`.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2897229/4108884) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", function() {
      
        var $txt = $("#txt");
        var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
       console.log(caretPos);
        console.log(textAreaTxt[caretPos]);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<input id="txt" rows="15" cols="70"/>

</body>
</html>
```

[Something like this?](https://jsbin.com/zeduhomeyo/1/edit?html,js,console,output) this essentially builds off quik_silv [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery) you get the index value of the cursor then get the value of the text field and retrieve a value by the index it's on a button click but could be easily changed

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var $txt = $("#txt");
    var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();

    console.log(caretPos);
    console.log(textAreaTxt[caretPos]);
});
```

Comment: Your code returns a character instead of a position... put it's on the right track

Comment: @ncohen my bad! Changed it for you

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try this

<input id="text" type="text" value="EXAMPLE" size="20" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var length = this.value.length;
    var x =length-(length-this.selectionStart)
alert(x);
},
false);
```