# Insert text into a textarea where cursor is (not appending to the end)

Tags: jquery

So, I have a textarea which I'm wanting to add text into via a click of a button.

However, when I'm doing this, it's appending to the end of the box rather than where my cursor is. How can I achieve this?

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ukLaz8cm/127/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({

    pickerPosition: "right",
    tonesStyle: "bullet",
    events: {
      keyup: function(editor, event) {
        console.log(editor.html());
        console.log(this.getText());
      }
    }
  });
});

$('.aClass').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default behaviour of a tag 
  var val = $('#emojionearea1').data("emojioneArea").getText(); //get prvious value
  if ($(this).text() == 'Test 1') {
    $('#emojionearea1').data("emojioneArea").setText(val + "\r\n" + 'Thank You');
  } else {
    $('#emojionearea1').data("emojioneArea").setText(val + "\r\n" + 'Good Luck');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
}

.row:after,
.row:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.span6 {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 1%;
}

.emojionearea-standalone {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<a href="#" class="aClass" data-text="Thank You">Test 1</a> Clicking this will add "Thank you" to textarea<br/>
<a href="#" class="aClass" data-text="Good Luck">Test 2</a> Clicking this will add "Good luck" to textarea<br/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <textarea id="emojionearea1"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Full working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ukLaz8cm/127/

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the text of whole text area.

Look into this [Inserting a text where cursor is using Javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery)