# Turn input text to uppercase, only if the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkbox and input text and I need turn input charaters to uppercase, only when checkbox is checked.

So, if checkbox is not checked and and I type "aa", then check checkbox and type "bb", result should be: "aaBB"

I have this code but this is incorrect, as it turns entire input value to uppercase, when checkbox is checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    if ($("#ch").is(":checked")) {
      this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch" />
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqa8p9ub/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with plain JavaScript using the `keypress` event and adding the character uppercased or not to the current input value depending on your checkbox state.

Using the `keypress` event is preferable to using `keyup` since you can intercept the key before it gets added to the input, which allows you to transform it or not or even discard it. Using `keyup` however forces you to change the whole input value since the value will already have been added to the input. You may also see a small flicker in this case.

Also you have to prevent the event from finishing executing by calling `event.preventDefault()`, otherwise the character will be added twice to the input.

You also need to insert the character at the right position using `input.selectionStart`. Once inserted, you have to increment both `input.selectionStart` and `input.selectionEnd`, see [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery).

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('#ch');
const input = document.querySelector('#myinp');

input.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  const checked = checkbox.checked;
  const char = checkbox.checked ? event.key.toLocaleUpperCase() : event.key;
  const pos = input.selectionStart || 0;
  input.value = input.value.slice(0, pos) + char + input.value.slice(pos);
  input.selectionStart = pos + 1;
  input.selectionEnd = pos + 1;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ch" />
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

Comment: Nice, but if type  some text, then focus cursor at beginning of input and type some text again, text will added at the end of input, not there, where cursor is currently

Comment: @OTAR, I updated the code to insert at the right place using input.selectionStart

Comment: Gracias my friend

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function(e) {
        if ($("#ch").is(":checked")) {
          let lastChar = e.key;
          lastChar = lastChar.toUpperCase();
          this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1) + lastChar;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch" />
<input type="text" id="myinp" />
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/Q0aigCO1j