# insert at caret instead of replace entire textarea

Tags: php, replace, insert, textarea, caret

I am modifying a third party application and within that application, I have this code:

```
            <?php if (!$this->allowEditor) { ?>
            $('#ticket_message').val(data.text);
            <?php } else { ?>
            jInsertEditorText(data.text, 'ticket_message');
            <?php } ?>
```

On the page that I need the modification, it is running the `if` statement. And what it currently does is replacing the content of the textarea `#ticket_message` but is there also a way it inserts it into the textarea without overwriting existing content.

It would be even better if it inserts it at the last location where the user stopped typing so at the caret.

For instance > TEXTAREA:

```
Lorem ipsum dolar sit met.

INSERT IT HERE BECAUSE THIS IS THE LAST PLACE THE TEXT CURSOR(caret) WAS SET

Lorem ipsum dolar sit met.
```

Comment: Maybe look at https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append values

```
$('#ticket_message').append(new_val);
```

to insert at caret you can use the following function

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId,text) {
var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
var strPos = 0;
var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
if (br == "ie") { 
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
}
else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
txtarea.value=front+text+back;
strPos = strPos + text.length;
if (br == "ie") { 
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
    range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
    range.select();
}
else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
}
txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

Comment: It did not solve the problem. It only gives a direction. If your answer is fully worked out it is still only appending and not inserting at the caret. Therefore the +1 but not the solved answer.

Comment: okay fine. you can check what you need exactly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Thank you very much this is really helpful. I am wondering what did you type in to get to this answer. Because I did not find it before posting. This is a nice solution thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While Amit Sharma gave me very useful information in my case I did need to go a different route. So depending on your need one of these answers should get you a lot closer to your result.

```
<?php if (!$this->allowEditor) { ?>
  var $txt = $("#ticket_message");
  var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
  var txtToAdd = data.text;
  $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
<?php } else { ?>
  jInsertEditorText(data.text, 'ticket_message');
<?php } ?>
```

This code is adapted from here: https://www.codehaven.co.uk/jquery/jquery-strings/insert-text-at-cursor-position-jquery/