# Basic JS: Adding characters at cursor position, while maintaining cursor position

Tags: javascript

Say I am making a basic Calculator that allows whole expressions to typed by the user. I'll use a simple `<input>` tag.

The user can type whatever they want, but I want to make it even easier for the client, I want to add a closing parenthesis immediately after they type `(`, so I set up my javascript to detect when `(` is input by into the input field, then `+=` a `)` to the input field.

The problem with my code is that it adds the parenthesis to the **end** of the input, regardless of where they type the parenthesis, even at the beginning.

How can I add a character where ever the cursor is?

My code is as follows:

```js
input = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");

input.addEventListener(`keyup`, (event)=>
{
  if(event.key === `(`)
  {
    input.value+=`)`;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Put mathematical expression"></input>
```

Comment: This is answered here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: And here too -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that should solve your problem.

```
let input = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");

input.addEventListener(`keyup`, (event) => {
    if(event.key === '(') {
        let cursorPos = input.selectionStart;
        input.value = input.value.substr(0, cursorPos) + ')' + 
                      input.value.substr(cursorPos);
    }   
});
```